# Input type date looks different on device than chrome emulator

Tags: css, mobile

I am trying to access native date picker on a mobile platform. I used `input type="date"` and styled it according to design. After testing on iPhone, native date picker was working perfectly but date input looks different than Chrome mobile device emulator. Different browsers on iPhone showed date input the same way as Chrome, so it doesn't seem to be a browser thing.
Do you have experience with this? Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

`<input type="date" />`

Styles:

```
input[type=date] {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6d9;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* Hide arrow */
  &::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

}
```

Difference in showing date input:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `-webkit-appearance: none;` as shown below:

```
input{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```